# ionic Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios8, ionic-framework

I'm having an issue with Ionic projects after updating to Xcode 6 and iOS 8.

When trying to run projects I get the following error in Xcode:

```
Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server.
```

The full log is:

```
2014-10-11 14:08:29.468 test[23293:109668] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.6.3 is starting.
2014-10-11 14:08:29.469 test[23293:109668] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-10-11 14:08:29.495 test[23293:109668] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-10-11 14:08:29.866 test[23293:109668] [CDVTimer][keyboard] 0.079989ms
2014-10-11 14:08:29.866 test[23293:109668] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 0.284970ms
2014-10-11 14:08:30.721 test[23293:109668] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-10-11 14:08:30.764 test[23293:109668] Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server.
```

Even when trying to update Ionic and Cordova and starting a new project this error keeps popping up.

I couldn't find any threads with this particular error and I'm not sure if this is an iOS 8 compatibility issue or something is messed up with my setup.

Thanks!

EDIT:

A bit more info on what's in the index.html and app.js

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <!-- compiled CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/app-0.0.1.css" />

    <!-- compiled JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body >
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


    <!-- Load deferred scripts -->

    <!-- Google Maps -->
    <script src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback=googleMapsLoaded' defer async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and app.js (before compilation with the rest of the files using ngbp):

```
angular.module( 'app', [
  'ionic',

  // Common requirements
  'templates-app',
  'templates-common',

  // Common Components
  'app.auth',

  // All page modules
  'app.businesses',
  'app.business',
  'app.search',
  'app.branch',
  'app.profile',
  'app.feed',

  // Other dependencies
  'ui.router'
])

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function myAppConfig ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "menu/menu.tpl.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise( 'app/feed' );
}])

.run(['$ionicPlatform', 'appAuthService', '$sessionStorage', function($ionicPlatform, appAuthService, $sessionStorage) {
  // Initialize ionic styles
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      StatusBar.styleLightContent();
    }
  });

  // Initialize app authentication service
  appAuthService.init();

  // Initialize a session cache validation object
  $sessionStorage.updated = {};
}])

.controller( 'AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function AppCtrl ($scope, $location) {

}])

;
```

Comment: Have you verified that the server you want to connect to is even available?

Comment: you need to show us how your `index.html` has been coded. Need to provide more information?

Comment: @ScottHunter I have, though even if it's not available and the app's resources are local ionic should still load, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 98):

I had the same problem.

I opened the ios project in the platform folder via Xcode, but I forgot that the codebase in the Xcode folder was not up to date and therefore broken.

To get the new code in your Xcode project use the command:

```
ionic cordova prepare ios
```

If your problem is rooted in the same as mine this should help.

Comment: In new versions of Ionic `ionic cordova prepare ios`

Comment: In 2021 it would be `ionic cap build ios`

Answer (score 24):

This error may also occur if you open the project using Xcode after used the live debugging with the emulator

> ionic cordova emulate ios --livereload -lc

To solve the issue, close Xcode and build the project again using

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Then build and run using Xcode.

Comment: +1 - this also breaks your app using capacitor - the reason being is the server url is populated to your *local* url which means it will work on your local machine/devices but when you deploy boom it stops working as its trying to reach your LAN ip. the `server` block should be removed from `capacitor.config.json`

Comment: Actually, this was the case in my situation

Answer (score 17):

I encountered this issue when I tried to run my Ionic 4 app on an iOS device.

What solved it for me, was running the dev server on all network interfaces using the `--address` option, for example:

`ionic cordova run ios --address=0.0.0.0 --debug --consolelogs -l`

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue using XCode9.3 and ionic3. Turns out that the issue was caused by missing configurations in "config.xml" needed for WKWebview to function properly. I added the following snippet to my config.xml, before deleting the "platforms/ios" folder and running "ionic cordova build ios --prod" again.

```html
 <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

See [link here](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) for a more detailed explanation from the ionic team.

Answer (score 1):

I have run the server and simulator and again am trying to update the app on the device.

Then I had the same problem

I stoped my simulator and re builded the app and opened the project.xcodeproj file with Xcode and run it on the device.This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, reinstalling the **cordova-plugin-ionic-webview** worked for me.

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case (under IONIC 5) the entry

```
"server": {
    "url": "http://192.168.0.6:8100"
  }
```

in the file "capacitor.config.json" had to be deleted.
Afterwards the app ran smoothly on mobile devices.

Comment: Ok I'll Delete the capacitor.config.json. Where does the entry provided go please?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, i hope it helps:
https://github.com/glebmachine/cordova-plugin-ionic/commit/7c095a45a13f7349e93f14a3057153775109f635

To install from my fork: 

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/glebmachine/cordova-plugin-ionic.git#v4`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This error may also be caused if the test device is **not connected properly to the WiFi network**. Both your development machine (i.e., Laptop) and the test device (i.e., mobile device/phone) must be connected to the same WiFi network.

For testing on actual device with live reload run the following command:

```
ionic cordova run ios -l --external
```