# Q: Ionic 3 - IOS Failed to load webpage with error: A server with the specified hostname could not be found

Tags: ios, xcode, angular, ionic3

I am getting the attached error message from xcode whenever I try to run my ionic 3 project on simulator ios 11. May I know if there is anyone else getting same issue? I created a new project with blank starter template, still getting the same error message.

[image: xcode log]

UPDATE : tried with ios 9.3 simulator - same result .

UPDATE 2 : re-install xcode - same result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314005/ionic-failed-to-load-webpage-with-error-could-not-connect-to-the-server)

Comment: Try `ionic cordova prepare ios`

Answer (score 1):

For those that might have the same problem, and prepare doesn't work, if you use some kind of local hosts management software (like mamp) check if your /etc/hosts file is not empty (or if localhost is recognized by your machine > ping localhost). If so, reset it to:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Can you post that solution also to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314005/ionic-failed-to-load-webpage-with-error-could-not-connect-to-the-server of which this seems to be a duplicate?